# Using regex in preg_replace to match an html href anchor tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to replace

```
&lt;a href=&quot;WWW.ANYURL.COM&quot;&gt;DISPLAY_TEXT&lt;/a&gt;
```

with

```
<a href="WWW.ANYURL.COM">DISPLAY_TEXT</a>
```

here is my code:

```
$string = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($string1)); 
$newString = preg_replace('#&lt;a\ href=&quot;([^&]*)&quot;&gt;([^&]*)&lt;/a&gt;#','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$string);
```

If I do limited tests such as:

```
$newString = preg_replace('#&lt;a\ href#','TEST',$string);
```

then

```
&lt;a href=&quot;WWW.ANYURL.COM&quot;&gt;DISPLAYTEXT&lt;/a&gt;
```

becomes

```
TEST=&quot;WWW.ANYURL.COM&quot;&gt;DISPLAYTEXT&lt;/a&gt;
```

But if I try to get it to also match the "=" it acts as if it could't find a match, i.e.

```
$newString = preg_replace('#&lt;a\ href=#','TEST',$string);
```

returns the original unchanged:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;WWW.ANYURL.COM&quot;&gt;DISPLAY_TEXT&lt;/a&gt;
```

I've been going at this for a couple hours, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: code in context

```
$title = clean_input($_POST['title']);
$story = clean_input($_POST['story']);

function clean_input($string) 
  { 
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
   $string = stripslashes($string);
  }
$string = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($string)); 
$findValues = array("&lt;b&gt;","&lt;/b&gt;");
$newValues = array("<b>", "</b>");
$newString = str_replace($findValues, $newValues, $string);
$newString2 = preg_replace('#&lt;a\ href=&quot;([^&]*)&quot;&gt;([^&]*)&lt;/a&gt;#','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$newString);
return $newString2;
}
```

Sample $story = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` Vivamus quis sem felis. Morbi vitae neque ac neque blandit malesuada lobortis sit amet justo. Donec convallis, nibh ut lacinia tempor, neque felis scelerisque nibh, at feugiat lectus erat in nulla. In et euismod nunc. `<pernicious code></code>`Pellentesque vitae ante orci, vitae ultrices neque. `<a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>` In non nulla sapien, vestibulum faucibus metus. Fusce egestas viverra arcu, `<b>ac</b>` sagittis leo facilisis in. Nulla facilisi.

I want only a few tags like href and bold to be allowed through as code.

Comment: Uh... um.. anyone else see logical issues with this question?

Comment: Wait - what are you trying to do?  Why did you use `htmlentities` if you're going to just undo the work of `htmlentities`?

Comment: Most people would use `html_entity_decode()` and just get on with more important things...

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but maybe `strip_tags($str, '<a>')` gives you a proper result instead of `htmlentities()`

Comment: I want to only undo the work on certain tags. I'm trying to sanitize a string to add to a database but allow certain safe html markup.

Comment: If you want to sanitize HTML input, then look into http://htmlpurifier.org/ rather than doing it by hand.

Comment: I will look into it, I would still like to know why the equals sign seems to be causing a failure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to manually replace anything. If this is your whole input string, then use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to turn the escapes back into `<` and `>`.

---

Again, your regex works as intended with the sample text.

Your problem is the **premature `mysql_real_escape_string()`** call. It adds backslashes to the `"` double quotes in your html, and that's why back-converting fails (your regex is not prepared for finding `\&quot;`).

Avoid  that. Get rid of the ugly `clean_string()` hack and **magic_quotes** as [advised by the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). You must do the database escaping **right before** inserting into the database, not earlier. (Or better yet use the easier [PDO with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PDO%20with%20prepared%20statements).)

Also avoid the `$newString123` variable duplicates, just overwrite the one you already have when rewriting strings.

Comment: It's not my whole input string

Comment: So what was the problem with your first complete `preg_replace` then?

Comment: The code does work. I tried it out. Please precisise your question.

Comment: You tried

$newString = preg_replace('#&lt;a\ href=&quot;([^&]*)&quot;&gt;([^&]*)&lt;/a&gt;#','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$string);

and it worked?

Comment: Alright, if that is the case then something very strange is going on. I tried the whole thing and it doesn't replace anything, if I try sections of it they all work unless I include the equals sign (see original post). I'm running a wamp stack, could some difference in what we are running be causing the failure on my end?

Comment: You could check your `print PCRE_VERSION;` but your regex is not complex enough to trigger any bugs, so unless it's before 8.x this is not the cause. Add the `#imsu` flags to your regex also. Otherwise it's something else that you overlook and is not displayed in your question examples.

Comment: I added my code in context, see if anything hits you as wrong.

Comment: See update. It's the mysql escaping which turns `"` into `\"` and the `\&quot;` is subsequently not found by the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this:

```
$str = "&lt;a href=&quot;WWW.ANYURL.COM&quot;&gt;DISPLAY_TEXT&lt;/a&gt;";
echo "Your html code is thus: " . htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Comment: That would be fine is that was my whole string but I want to be able to take several paragraphs with any variation of possible markup and match only hrefs